# Appium (1.6.3) stop sending command to android device

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, serenity-bdd

While running serenity project, appium stop sending command to android device after some time with this log repeated “[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session - - ms  - -”. How can I restart appium instance without disrupting ongoing test?

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. Appium is able to connect to the device and open chrome but stops in this command `[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 34895 ms - 603 ` No more instructions are sending to chrome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't restart appium server during run of the test, session will be lost.
But it is possible to restart appium between each test in test suite.